# swift 4: Unable to parse JSON response

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am VERY NEW to Swift and IOS developing ...

I am using Alamofire and SwityJSON to post to an API endpoint for authentication and I am purposely entering wrong credentials to code an indication to the user.

```
Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let rspJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                if JSON(msg.self) == "Invalid Credentials" {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Those credentials are not recognized.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{(action) in self.clearLogin()}))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
                else {
                    print(rspJSON)
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Error \(response)")
            }
        }
```

The output of print(rspJSON) is

> {   "msg" : "Invalid Credentials" }

so I would expect that the if JSON(msg.self) == "Invalid Credentials" conditional would hit but apparently it is not because the output of the print() statement is visible and no alert can be seen.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While parsing your JSON, always find keys in response in the dictionary. Like in this case, you wanted value of 'msg', you have to parse using

```
if let message = res["msg"] as? String {}
```

as? String casts the response into the expected data type.

```
Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if let res = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
            if let message = res["msg"] as? String {
                if message == "Invalid Credentials" {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Those credentials are not recognized.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{(action) in self.clearLogin()}))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: no errors but no alert either ... do I have to import something to use NSDictionary? Currently I am importing

Comment: import UIKit
import Firebase
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

Comment: Please Post the response from the API

Comment: Also change if message = "Invalid Credentials" to if message == "Invalid credentials"

Comment: I added print(res) under your declaration and received {
    msg = "Invalid Credentials";
}

Comment: and I had changed to "==" prior to the test

Comment: I also added print(message) under your if let message = .... and it is not outputting